# If the value of $\int_{1}^2{e^{x^{2}}}dx$ is $\alpha$, then what is $\int_{e}^{e^{4}}{\sqrt{\log x}}dx$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

If the value of $\int_{1}^2{e^{x^{2}}}dx$ is $\alpha$, then what is $$\int_{e}^{e^{4}}{\sqrt{\log x}}dx$$

It just seems that substitution of any sort does not help. Is there some other way in which these two integrals are related?

The answer is $2e^4 - e - \alpha$

Comment: Try an extra step of integration by parts after the obvious substitution.

Comment: Or think the geometric way ($x\mapsto e^{x^2}$ and $x\mapsto\sqrt{\log x}$ are inverse to each other).

Comment: @metamorphy How does that help?

Comment: Here's a general formula: If $f$ is continuous and one-to-one on $[a,b]$ 
$$\int_a^b f^{-1}(x)~dx=[xf^{-1}(x)]_a^b-\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)} f(u)~du$$
This suggests using integration by parts and integration by substitution.

Comment: @projectilemotion If it is an elementary proof, could you direct me to a page? This seems interesting.

Comment: Sure, see for instance [Proving the integral of an inverse function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701331/proving-the-integral-of-an-inverse-function).

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=e^{x^2}\iff log y =x^2\iff \sqrt{\log y}=x$$
The rectangle bounded by $(1,0), (2,0),(1,e^4), (2,e^4)$ has area $e^4.$
The regions represented by the two integrals fill this rectangle with
an excess of a $1\times(e^4-e)$-rectangle that touches the Y-axis.
(In the second integral, interchange $x$ and $y$ and use the equivalence displayed above.)
Therefore, $$\int_{e}^{e^{4}}{\sqrt{\log x}}\,dx=e^4 + (e^4-e)-a=2e^4 -e-a.$$

Answer (score 4):

Take $t=\sqrt{\log x}$ then $x=e^{t^2}$ and $dx=2te^{t^2}$. So
$$I=\int_e^{e^4}\sqrt{\log x}dx=\int_1^22t^2e^{t^2}dt.
$$
Using integration by parts: $u=t$ $dv=2te^{t^2}dt$, you'll get that $v=e^{t^2}$ and
$$I=te^{t^2}\bigg|_1^2-\int_1^2e^{t^2}dt=2e^4-e-\alpha
$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Clear and concise.